# How to make a string only have letters in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
from random import randint
Text = ""
Text2 = ""
Text3 = ""
Final = ""
Final2 = ""
inp = input(str("What's your name?"))
Greet = randint(1,3)
File = open("File2.txt","w")
File.write(inp+",")
File.write("YoYoYo,")
File.write("Hi,")
File.write("Hey,")
File.close()
File = open("File2.txt","r")
for line in File:
    Text = line.split(",")

Text2 = (Text[Greet])
Text3 = Text[0]
Final = (Text2,Text3)
Final = str(Final)
print(Final)
File.close()
```

Because I am setting the Variable "Final" using parts from a list this is the result:

```
What's your name?Mark
('YoYoYo', 'Mark')
```

I want it to print it normally without the brackets, comma and `''` like:

```
YoYoYo Mark
```

Is there a way I can easily remove the brackets, comma and `''`?

Problem sorted ;p Thanks <3

Comment: You see that because you have a tuple, not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(Text2,Text3)` is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), tuples are printed that way, if you want a string that is the composition of other strings, you should concatenate the other strings using the `+` operator:

```
Final = Text2 + ' ' + Text3
print(Final) # => YoYoYo Mark
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Pass them to the `print` function directly:

You are assigning a `tuple` to the variable `Final` and then printing it which prints with brackets as it is a `tuple`. You don't need to bother with any of that as you can just pass both `Text2` and `Text3` directly into the `print()` function:

```
print(Text2, Text3)
```

and they will `print` with a space between them:

```
YoYoYo Mark
```